# sql query to bring last letter in a string to first letter position using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name called 'Supervisor' from a table JobData in a Mysql database. In this 'Supervisor' column the records are of the format "SPARKSL", "ADITYAG", "KENTONS", "DRISCOLLJ" and so on. I want to convert these records to lower case and bring the last letter to first letter.For example "SPARKSL" should be changed to the format "lsparks" and this format should be applied to all the remaining records.

Can anyone help me out with a SQL query for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with basically `left()` and `right()` to extract the parts, `concat()` to put them together (in reverse order) and `lower()` to transform to lower case.

```
SELECT lower(concat(right(supervisor, 1), left(supervisor, length(supervisor) - 1)))
       FROM jobdata;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01ae6/6)

Or, if you want an update:

```
UPDATE jobdata
       SET supervisor = lower(concat(right(supervisor, 1), left(supervisor, length(supervisor) - 1)));
```

(But be aware, this will update **all** rows! Add a `WHERE` clause, if you don't want that to happen.)

Comment: Thanks for your  reply @sticky bit. But, unfortunately the above concat query wasn't working. I was getting an error called "length is not a recognized built in function name".

Comment: And I don't want to use the update query since this table gets updated everyday. So, I don't want to come back everyday and update the table using the update query

Comment: @adityagoud . . . `length()` is definitely a function that is available in MySQL (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length).  If you are not using MySQL, figure out the database that you are using and ask another question with the appropriate tag.

Comment: The database I'm using is MSSQL server not MySQL. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue

Comment: @adityagoud: The equivalent in SQL Server is `len()`. Next time tag correctly and don't write "... in a Mysql database ...", to prevent such misunderstandings.